# Access previous 'synthetic' column in select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

If I have a select statement like this

```
SELECT 
   t.time,
   <complicated computation> AS ticks,
   <is it possible to access the value of the ticks row here?> as num
FROM
   MyTable t;
```

Can I use the calculated value in column 2 as basis for calculations in column 3?

Comment: No. Only with correlated subqueries.

Comment: @Alexander: Can you give me an example? In an answer to this question? Thanks.

Comment: [something like this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16318730/mysql-calculation-in-select-statement).

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap this in a subquery: it will look like this:

```
SELECT
    i.time as time,
    i.ticks as ticks,
    i.ticks + 10 as num
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       t.time as time,
       5 AS ticks
    FROM
       MyTable t
) AS i;
```